# External screen on iOS not updating

Tags: ios, swift

This function gets run when an external screen gets connected to the device (I can print to console when the function runs), but the external screen doesn't display the label and the view isn't white. What am I missing?

```
func displayConnected(notification: Notification) {
    let extScreen = notification.object as! UIScreen
    let extWindow = UIWindow(frame: extScreen.bounds)
    extWindow.screen = extScreen

    let extVC = UIViewController()
    extWindow.rootViewController = extVC

    let extView = UIView(frame: extWindow.frame)

    //customize extView
    extView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    extWindow.addSubview(extView)
    extWindow.isHidden = false

    let externalLabel = UILabel()
    externalLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    externalLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 50.0)
    externalLabel.frame = extView.bounds
    externalLabel.text = "Hello"
    externalLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    extView.addSubview(externalLabel)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you read the docs? `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIScreenDidConnect, 
                    object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
   // Get the new screen information.
   let newScreen = notification.object as! UIScreen
   let screenDimensions = newScreen.bounds
            
   // Configure a window for the screen.
   let newWindow = UIWindow(frame: screenDimensions)
   newWindow.screen = newScreen
   // Install a custom root view controller in the window.
   self.configureAuxilliaryInterface(with: newWindow)`

Comment: `// You must show the window explicitly.
   newWindow.isHidden = false
   // Save a reference to the window in a local array.
   self.additionalWindows.append(newWindow)}`  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/displaying_content_on_a_connected_screen

Comment: I've read the docs on it. Are you talking specifically about including the ref? I would assume UIScreen.screens takes care of it. Otherwise, I believe I have covered everything the docs suggest?

Comment: Why are you adding your subviews to the window instead of the view controller's view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs a reference to the window in a local array.

So, add this to your vc class:

```
var additionalWindows = [UIWindow]()
```

And this to your function:

```
self.additionalWindows.append(extWindow)
```